# concatenate files awk/linux

Tags: linux, awk, concatenation

I have n files in a folder which starts with lines as shown below.

```
##contig=<ID=chr38,length=23914537>
##contig=<ID=chrX,length=123869142>
##contig=<ID=chrMT,length=16727>
##samtoolsVersion=0.1.19-44428cd
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  P922_120
chr1    412573  SNP74   A       C       2040.77 PASS    AC=2;AC1=2;AF=1.00;AF1=1;AN=2;DB;DP=58;
chr1    602567  BICF2G630707977 A       G       877.77  PASS    AC=2;AC1=2;AF=1.00;AF1=1;AN=2;DB;  
chr1    604894  BICF2G630707978 A       G       2044.77 PASS    AC=2;AC1=2;AF=1.00;AF1=1;AN=2;DB;
chr1    693376  .       GCCCCC  GCCCC   761.73  .       AC=2;AC1=2;AF=1.00;AF1=1;
```

There are n such files. I want to concatenate all the files into a single file such that all the lines begining with # should be deleted from all the files and concatenate the rest of the rows from all the files only retaining the header line. Example output is shown below:

```
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  P922_120
chr1    412573  SNP74   A       C       2040.77 PASS    AC=2;AC1=2;AF=1.00;AF1=1;AN=2;DB;DP=58;
chr1    602567  BICF2G630707977 A       G       877.77  PASS    AC=2;AC1=2;AF=1.00;AF1=1;AN=2;DB;  
chr1    604894  BICF2G630707978 A       G       2044.77 PASS    AC=2;AC1=2;AF=1.00;AF1=1;AN=2;DB;
chr1    693376  .       GCCCCC  GCCCC   761.73  .       AC=2;AC1=2;AF=1.00;AF1=1;
```

Comment: thanks everyone. But, the header line "#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  P922_120" should be retained only once as a header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically with awk:

```
awk '$0!~/^#/{print $0}' file1 file2 file3 > outputfile
```

Broken down you are checking if the line ($0) does not match (!~) a string beginning with # (/^#/) and if so, print the line.  You take input files and write to (>) outputfile.

Comment: Huh? Surely that will remove the header that starts with `#`.

Comment: Thanks. If there are n files there will be n header lines. And your solution completely removes header from all files. It should be retained once as a header as shown in the output.

Comment: If you only need the headers once, either manually put it in which is probably the easier option, or try:  `awk 'BEGIN{f=""};$0~/#C/&&f!="T"{print $0;f="T"};$0!~/^#/{print $0}' file1 file2 > outfile`

Comment: Which works by setting a flag (f) when the header is printed.  Every time it reaches a header it then checks if it's already printed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not terribly well specified, but I think you are just looking for:

```
sed '/^##/d' $FILE_LIST > output
```

Where `FILE_LIST` is the list of input files( you may be able to use `*`)

Comment: thanks!! still minor issue. It prints all lines begining with "#" i.e. #CHROM header lines from all files. It should be printed only once. Can we fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `grep` like this:

```
grep -vh "^##" *
```

The `-v` means `inverted`, so the command means... look for all lines NOT starting `##` in all files and don't print filenames (`-h`).

Or, if you want to emit 1 header line at the start,

```
(grep -m1 ^#CHROM * ; grep -hv ^## * ) > out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you could do:

```
echo "#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  P922_120" > mergedfile
for file in $FILES; do cat $file | grep -v "#" >> mergedfile; done
```

Note that $FILES could be `ls` and the -v option in grep is the non-match flag.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is

```
awk '$0 ~/^##/ { next; } $0 ~ /^#/ && !printed_header {print; printed_header=1 } $0! ~ /^#/ {print }' file1 file2 file3
```